# Is this OK to ask questions that have been asked before on local artificial intelligence forums?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, asking-questions

As you might know sites remain in private beta for three weeks:

[We've extended the private betas to last about three weeks total.](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/75/237)

[Usually new communities are concerned that we didn't give them enough time.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266555/226369)

And I think in this three weeks, the core users should try their best to enrich the site's content.
I think we should ask questions that are easily google-enabled and a usual concern for most of artificial intelligence researchers that are even asked before in other forums (local forums maybe). This way, after the end of private beta if someone googles that question and sees that are site has better answered the question, they'll rely on our site and it is more probable to become a member of the site and ask their future questions in the site.
Any way are questions should not be opinion-based, subjective, etc.
In fact I'm not an expert or research-level student. I'm a remote sensing student with some experience in photogrammetry and programming with OpenGL API on C++. 
So I cannot add good questions myself but I'm really curious about everything related to accelerating the code and real-time programming.
Anyway since I'm an Iranian, I wanted to know if it's OK to translate good and popular questions in Iranian artificial intelligence forum which have the features of a good question that have introduced before or discussed about?

[Your New Site: Asking the First Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/)
[Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
[Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)
[Are Some Questions Too Simple?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/)

in order to enrich the content?
I think this way any Iranian who tries to google that question in English and then enters this site will see that the quality of answers is better here (because in these 3 weeks experts should try their best to add comprehensive answers) will be a fan of [ai.stackexchange.com](http://ai.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Related: http://meta.ai.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/can-i-steal-a-question-from-a-closed-site

Answer (score 6):

Most Stack Exchange sites (including this one) are English-only, and it's not expected that users will be able to use other languages. Therefore, if there are resources that are not available in English, it would be very good to make them accessible to English speakers somewhere, and this site would be a fine place for doing so.

Make sure, of course, that the question is good (i.e. well-researched, not trivially Google-able in English) and constructive (i.e. on-topic). To avoid accusations of cross-language plagiarism, try to paraphrase rather than translating word-for-word. In the same vein, link back to the original site when you draw heavily from it. That's all part of being a good Internet citizen. If you can improve the answer by drawing from additional sources, that's great too!

Relevant SE blog post: [Are some questions too simple?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/)

Comment: but here is not a place to provide resources, here is a place for question that you encounter during your research or project. And as I have seen on iranian forums most of them, don't have real expert question. Most of them are explanations about the applications of AI and also solutions for famous AI problems like `Travelling salesman problem`. Anyway since I haven't committed to this proposal, I'm not forced to ask 10 questions in this 3 weeks. But since I'm going to learn AI myself in the near future because of its application in remote sensing, this site will be really helpful for me.

Comment: @sepideh Right, you shouldn't *just* link to the external site; you should include its information and then cite it.

Comment: But I think the idea of this question can be really helpful for those who have committed to the proposal as far as they consider your advises. You won't have ten real expert questions in 21 days but you can translate ten real expert questions asked in local forums to english and let international experts add comprehensive answers which are better than the answers in that local forum.